# My emails are being put into updates by Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-categories

My Gmail account has suddenly started putting my new emails into the "updates" folder and I don't know how to stop this from happening. I want them to go directly into my inbox.

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is here. Please clarify your question. Note: Gmail does not use folders; it uses labels and categories. Please also review the advice at [ask].

Comment: The question actually is legitimate, and there is a "Categories" folder called "Updates".

Answer (score 6):

Click the "gear" icon on the right of Gmail screen and choose "Configure Inbox". Uncheck "Updates" and any other tabs / categories you do not need.

NEW:

Click the gear icon and click on "See All Settings". Select "Inbox". Uncheck "Updates". Scroll down and click on "Save".

[image: categories]

With only "Primary" tab left, inbox returns to its old behavior: all new messages appear together in the inbox.