# In Gmail, how does one disable emails from automatically filtering into the 'Updates', 'Promotions', etc. Categories?

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels, gmail-categories

I saw [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/116628/my-emails-are-being-put-into-updates-by-gmail?newreg=06eef0495ae94317b037443843fd6db8) years back, and to be honest, I already had them (ie. all Promotions, Social, Updates, & Forums) unchecked so that only 'Primary' is checked (located via the Gear icon->See all settings->'Inbox' tab). Today I even re-enabled and reloaded Gmail so that I could re-disable and reload Gmail. However, Gmail is still filtering into these categories... causing me to miss emails that should be going into my normal (aka Primary) Inbox.

Now I also have tons of custom filters set up (ie. skip inbox, apply Label 'xyz') yet some still go to the Category filters.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is still working, just select primary:

[image]

Successfully tested on 2 different Gmail accounts, on 2 different browsers.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Franck, but as I stated in my question, this is already exactly how my email is set up. And it doesn't prevent stuff from auto-moving into the categories tabs. 

I have custom filters that move messages into proper 'Labels' yet some of those messages are copied/dual filtered and are shown in both my selected 'Label' AND the 'Category'. Problem is that if I don't have a custom filter set for a new emailer, it may never appear in my 'Inbox/Primary' and is instead sent to a 'Category'.